# Double Pointer manipulated

Tags: c++, c, pointers, void-pointers

The double Pointer Manipulated.
Suggest for workaround.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
/* Pointer Passed as argument */
void func(void **p1)
{
     printf("Func %d\n",*p1);
}
/* main Function */
int main()
{ 
 void **p1 = NULL;
 int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
 p[0] = 20;
 func((void**)&p);//pass by address
 //How can we assign double pointer i.e (*p1 = &p)
 printf("Main %d",*p);   // print value
 cin.get();
 return 0;   
}
//function end main.cpp
/*
Func " Garbage value "
Main 20
*/
```

I am trying to use the double pointer to retreive data.
Can someone look into this and let me know where is the bug.

output ahould be 20 - 20
    Func 20
    Main 20

Comment: what is the question? what do you expect and what is the actual output?

Comment: I want this code to work

Comment: @PragRao what output you are getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C or C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Comment: This code is not C - the tag should be removed, but that edit alone is too small to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printf in the function should be:

```
printf("Func %d\n", *((int*)*p1));
```

In the function, `p1` has the address of the integer pointer `int * p`. This means dereferencing it once like `*p1` is equivalent to the original pointer `p`. Hence we cast it to an `int *` and dereference it again to get the value.

Comment: how can i do the same in main funcion . if i want to assign double pointer to single pointer . without calling the function.

Comment: you can do int ** p1 = &p. Then to get the value, you can dereference it twice like *(*p1). If you want to use void **, it should be void **p1=&p; and dereference should be the same : *((int *)*p1)

Comment: @PragRao - `printf("Main %d",*((int *)*((  (void**)&p))));`

Comment: void ** p1 = &p; // func((void**)&p); printf("Main %d",p[0]); printf("Func %d\n",* ((int*)*p1)); this gives error invalid conversion from int** to void**

Comment: sorry for missing this out : void **p1 = (void **) &p; ( I missed the cast )

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do in `func(void **p1)`:

```
printf("Func %d\n",*((int *)*p1));
```

You have to dereference it one more time to get the `int` value - since its a pointer-to-pointer.

And, [do not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (applicable only for C). In C++ the cast is required (better use the [`new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/) operator).

In main you can directly do this:

```
  printf("Main %d",*((int *)*((  (void**)&p))));
```

Comment: Since you tagged C++ and C both the information regarding malloc is applicable only for C

Comment: in C++ `malloc()` is discouraged (AFAIK)

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for that info again... OP has mixed and mashed C and C++... in C++ we include `cstdio` as well :)